# A lot of systemd messages since upgrade to Fedora 22

Tags: fedora, logs, systemd

I upgraded several systems to Fedora 22. After the upgrade I see every 10-20 seconds a lot of messages form `systemd`:

```
Aug 27 15:30:09 host.example.org systemd[1]: Created slice user-494.slice. 
Aug 27 15:30:09 host.example.org systemd[1]: Starting user-494.slice. 
Aug 27 15:30:09 host.example.org systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 494... 
Aug 27 15:30:09 host.example.org systemd[29383]: Reached target Timers. 
Aug 27 15:30:09 host.example.org systemd[29383]: Starting Timers. 
Aug 27 15:30:09 host.example.org systemd[29383]: Reached target Paths. 
Aug 27 15:30:09 host.example.org systemd[29383]: Starting Paths. 
Aug 27 15:30:09 host.example.org systemd[29383]: Reached target Sockets. 
Aug 27 15:30:09 host.example.org systemd[29383]: Starting Sockets. 
Aug 27 15:30:09 host.example.org systemd[29383]: Reached target Basic System. 
Aug 27 15:30:09 host.example.org systemd[29383]: Starting Basic System. 
Aug 27 15:30:09 host.example.org systemd[29383]: Reached target Default. 
Aug 27 15:30:09 host.example.org systemd[29383]: Startup finished in 8ms. 
Aug 27 15:30:09 host.example.org systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 494. 
Aug 27 15:30:09 host.example.org systemd[29383]: Starting Default. 
Aug 27 15:30:09 host.example.org audit[1]: <audit-1130> pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=user@494 comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success' 
Aug 27 15:30:09 host.example.org systemd-logind[636]: Removed session 1016. 
Aug 27 15:30:09 host.example.org systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 494... 
Aug 27 15:30:09 host.example.org systemd[29383]: Stopped target Default. 
Aug 27 15:30:09 host.example.org systemd[29383]: Stopping Default. 
Aug 27 15:30:09 host.example.org systemd[29383]: Stopped target Basic System. 
Aug 27 15:30:09 host.example.org systemd[29383]: Stopping Basic System. 
Aug 27 15:30:09 host.example.org systemd[29383]: Stopped target Sockets. 
Aug 27 15:30:09 host.example.org systemd[29383]: Stopping Sockets. 
Aug 27 15:30:09 host.example.org systemd[29383]: Stopped target Timers. 
Aug 27 15:30:09 host.example.org systemd[29383]: Stopping Timers. 
Aug 27 15:30:09 host.example.org systemd[29383]: Stopped target Paths. 
Aug 27 15:30:09 host.example.org systemd[29383]: Stopping Paths. 
Aug 27 15:30:09 host.example.org systemd[29383]: Reached target Shutdown. 
Aug 27 15:30:09 host.example.org systemd[29383]: Starting Shutdown. 
Aug 27 15:30:09 host.example.org systemd[29383]: Starting Exit the Session... 
Aug 27 15:30:09 host.example.org systemd[29383]: Received SIGRTMIN+24 from PID 29392 (kill). 
Aug 27 15:30:09 host.example.org systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 494. 
Aug 27 15:30:09 host.example.org audit[1]: <audit-1131> pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=user@494 comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success' 
Aug 27 15:30:09 host.example.org systemd[1]: Removed slice user-494.slice. 
Aug 27 15:30:09 host.example.org systemd[1]: Stopping user-494.slice.
```

Any idea what they could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, on Debian 8, I managed to turn off these excessive messages from `systemd` by setting:

in `/etc/systemd/user.conf: LogLevel=notice`

in `/etc/systemd/system.conf: LogLevel=notice`

in `/etc/systemd/journald.conf: MaxLevelSyslog=notice` Then applying changes : `systemctl restart systemd-journald` - be carefull with this one because no debug messages will be logged, (ex: maillog will be mostly empty), many log analyzers will no longer work.

For more information, `man systemd`